# Disable form field Django inlineformset_factory

Tags: python, django

Probably an easy one

I am trying to disable (i.e. that the field is present but greyed out) the 'sub_total' field on all formset lines and use javascript to update the field with whatever values are entered into the 'price_estimate' and 'quantity' fields.

I have the following models:

```
class Requisition(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True,)
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True)

class RequisitionLine(models.Model):
    requisition = models.ForeignKey(Requisition)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price_estimate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True)

    @property
    def get_sub_total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price_estimate
```

In my view I have

```
Formset = inlineformset_factory(models.Requisition,
                                models.RequisitionLine,
                                form = forms.RequsitionForm,
                                formset= forms.RequisitionLineForm,
                                fields=('product', 'price_estimate', 'quantity', 'sub_total'),
                                extra=2)
```

In forms

```
class RequsitionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Requisition
        fields = ['description']

class RequisitionLineForm(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):

    sub_total = forms.DecimalField(disabled=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.RequisitionLine
        fields = ['product', 'quantity', 'price_estimate', 'sub_total']
```

In addition to the code above - I have tried to modify the sub_total field on **init** however, whatever I try it seems that it is ignored.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected - very basic error. The view should look like this (i.e. not setting the formset flag.

```
Formset = inlineformset_factory(models.Requisition,
                                models.RequisitionLine,
                                form = forms.RequisitionLineForm,
                                fields=('product', 'price_estimate', 'quantity', 'sub_total'),
                                extra=2)
```

In addition to this - the form should be modified to use ModelForm (instead of BaseInlineFormSet)

```
class RequisitionLineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    sub_total = forms.DecimalField(disabled=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.RequisitionLine
        fields = ['product', 'quantity', 'price_estimate', 'sub_total']
```